# Issues using Sqlconnection with Visual Studio Express 10

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, visual-studio-2010, sqlconnection

I'm trying to make a mock inventory/customer database program for my employer. I'm new to C# and SQL, but not totally new to programming, with some basic knowledge of C++, php, and Basic, I went into this project feeling pretty confident, but this very simple problem is killing me. I've spent more than a few hours trying to just connect to my Northwind sample DB on my local SQL Compact 3.5 server which comes with VS 10 Express.

I decided to start simple and just try to connect, so I don't have any queries in my code. My very first attempt I copied and pasted some code which did have queries, but it didn't work so I started from scratch, still having the same issue.

I'm trying to use Sqlconnection(string), and it just never connects. The connection string I use is the one generated by Visual Studio. I've tried both DataDirectory and writing the directory in long form.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string connection = @"Data Source=|DataDirectory|\Northwind.sdf";
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connection);

        try
        {
            conn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show("Connection Successful!"); //Never happens
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("No connection."); // So tired of this message
        }

    }
```

I can not figure out what is wrong. I figured it was my data source string, but everything I  try gets the same result. I've tried searching for similar issues, and nothing seems to help. Most people seem to have issues with queries or code syntax, I can't even connect! I'm thinking I have something improperly configured with either VS or SQL. Any help is appreciated.

Here is a screen shot of a successful connection test and some of my settings.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/1mvri.jpg

Comment: try connectionstrings.com like the other answer suggested , just build it yourself based on the type of connection you are using

Comment: Useful site but none of the strings listed are working. Most aren't relevant to what I need, but I tried them all anyways and no luck. Could having both VS 10 Express and 12 Express installed be an issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your connection string like this:

```
string connection = @"Data Source=MyData.sdf;Persist Security Info=False;";
```

Check out [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-ce) for more info

**Update:**  You need to reference System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll, and use an SqlCeConnection object, like `new SqlCeConnection(connection)`

Comment: Just tried, @"Data Source=C:\Users\Travis\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\SQL Test\SQL Test\Northwind.sdf;Persist Security Info=False";, with no go. Thanks for the link, though. Looks helpful. Everything I've read says the string generated by VS should work, why wouldn't it?

Comment: @saganator see update, you are using the wrong connection object, sorry I missed that part from your code, try it with the *SqlCeConnection* object, and let me know how it goes.

Comment: Thanks Jason, this did the trick. I actually got it on my own late last night before bed, but forgot to update this. I'd give you some rep if I could.

Comment: @saganator Glad to hear you got, sometimes it's the very minor things that gets us going on a wild goose chase only to find out it was a silly mistake  :)